How do I retrieve more than 10k document in elasticsearch?
I'm completely new to ELK and trying to retrieve 40k documents.
the search_after depends on the previous batch of results and wasn't useful for me.
GET twitter/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "elasticsearch"
        }
    },
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
    "sort": [
        {"date": "asc"},
        {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
    ]
}

how to retrieve more than 10k documents?

are you trying to retrieve using code or from Kibana ? ES have option of scroll and search_after to retrieve more then 10k documents. You cant use any other option.

Does this answer your question? How do I retrieve more than 10000 results/events in Elasticsearch?

You can tweak the parameter max_result_window ,by default it is 10k you can increase this limit at time of index creation to 40k or other max limit you want.After this you can pass 40k in size parameter.
